# What is wrong with my application which uses the Vector class and while loop?

Tags: java, string, vector, while-loop

Could you guys give me some help over here with my not working application? First it has to prompt the user for a string for input and the prompt continues(`while-loop`) until when the user types "QUIT" which the application will then display the list of strings he/she has inputted by adding them into a `Vector`. Here's my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class TestVector {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String prompt = "Please enter a string or type QUIT to finish";
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Vector <String> names = new Vector <String>();
    System.out.println(prompt); 

    while(userInput.hasNextLine() && !(userInput.nextLine()).equals("QUIT"))
    {
        names.add(userInput.nextLine());
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Scanner userInput2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        names.add(userInput2.nextLine());
    }

    for(String s: names)
    {
        System.out.println("You typed: "):
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does it tell you where the error is?

Comment: repeatedly creating a new scanner will not work.

Comment: You are calling `nextLine()` twice in the condition and in the body of the while loop. I believe you want to either look for `QUIT` *or* store the name, but not add some random non-quit text and then enter the input.

Comment: @jhobbie it compiles and i'm using crimson editor anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String prompt = "Please enter a string or type QUIT to finish";
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Vector<String> names = new Vector<String>();
        System.out.println(prompt);

        String input = null;
        while (userInput.hasNextLine())
        {
            input = userInput.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("QUIT"))
                break;

            names.add(input);
        }

        for (String s : names)
        {
            System.out.println("You typed: ");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey hi thanks so much for your help i managed to get it working now. ;) btw, can i ask you something? I don't quite understand this bit whereby you declared the `String` variable, `input` as `null`? Erm why would you do that and why can't we declare it in the while loop as

    `String input = userInput.nextLine();`

Comment: Memory allocation. If you defined it before you are reusing the same area. If you put it inside of the loop then you are creating a new object and garbage collecting the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You created a Scanner and then immediately checked to see if it had input with `userInput.hasNextLine()`. This will always be false, and the body of your while loop will always be skipped.

If you want input from the user, just call `nextLine()`. Your program will then "wait" for the user to type something before it progresses. Here is an example:

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in); // cin is a commonly used name for "console input"
String s = cin.nextLine();            // Initial read
while (!s.equals("quit")) {           // Check input
    System.out.println(s);            // Do something with input, like print it
    s = cin.nextLine();               // Read
}
```

Comment: This loop will never end, if the first word isn't quit

Comment: @Typo Whoops, I forgot to read input inside the loop haha. Fixed now. For future reference, when obvious mistakes like that are made, use the edit button instead of insta downvoting.

Comment: @Rainbolt, well it's a way to call your attention. Don't sweat it, it happens to me all the time, hence the nick :D